# prove sub array has a definite form with distinct end point integers

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, arrays

An array has elements from set {0, 1, 2}. A span **SP** of an array is any interval *[start S, end E]* such that the sub array must contain all elements from {0,1,2}.

For example: in Array A = (0,1,0,1,1,2,0,1) we can say SP=[1,6] and SP=[5,8] but [1,5] is not a span as elements in array from index 1 to index 5 (0,1,0,1,1) do not contain {0,1,2}.
Here in the example array A minimum SP is [5,7] as it has only 3 elements (1,2,0) and maximum SP is [1,6] as it has 6 elements (0,1,0,1,1,2).

To find the number of elements in SP we can just (end E - start S + 1) i.e in the above example SP = [1,6] = 6 - 1 + 1 = 6 elements in this sub array (0,1,0,1,1,2)

How can i show that sub array of minimum SP is of the form $xy^{E -S - 1}z$ where (x,y,z) is a permutation of (0,1,2).

Comment: Why maximum SP is [1,6] instead of [1,8]?

Comment: The maximum SP will always be the entire array. I don't think that would be interesting anyways, so I think the question is better off not explaining about the maximum SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the array, and $B$ be the minimum span from $A$ (starting in $x$ and ending in $z$). We will prove that $x$ and $z$ only occur **once** in the subarray $B$.

Lets assume towards contradition, that $x$ occurs at least twice in $B$, and denote by $k$ the last index in $B$ at which $x$ appears. By our assumption, we know that $k>0$. Now we have two parts: either there occurs a $y$ after the index $k$, or there isn't.

- If there is a $y$ after the index $k$, then the subarray of $B$ starting at $k$ would have all three values: $x$ at $B[k]$, $y$ somewhere afterwards, and $z$ at the end. Hence, we proved that in this case $B$ isn't minimal (which contradicts our assumption on it).
- If there isn't a $y$ after $k$, then denote $m$ the last index at which $y$ appears. Since it doesn't appear after $k$, and $B[k]=x$, then $m<k$. But also $0<m$ since $B[0]=x$. Hence, the subarray of $B$ starting at $m$ would contain all three values: $x$ at $B[m]$, $y$ at $B[k]$, and $z$ at the end. But since $m>0$, then this subarray is smaller than $B$ which once again contradicts our assumptions on it.

You can prove the same way also for $z$.

Comment: your anwer makes sense for the fact that x and z appears only once and the middle element just repeats itself. But how can i say that span is of the form $^{nd−tart−1}$. very confused with this part.

Comment: This is an immediate implication of the fact that the minimum span contains only one $x$ and one $z$, and you know it starts and ends with them.